# CFT algebra calculation

Tags: conformal-field-theory, lie-algebra

Hi I'm reading https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.13280 and following its calculation but I'm stuck in page16, eqn 4.4a.

I got different result than the one in the paper, but I can't find the point I missed.
Here's my trial and someone can point out where I'm wrong?

cf) I know I used different notation, but I think big picture is same.

In paper $\sigma^\mu =(iI,\vec\sigma), \bar\sigma^\mu =(-iI,\vec\sigma)\quad M_\alpha^\beta = -\frac{1}{4}\sigma^{\mu\dot\alpha\beta}\sigma_\nu^{\alpha\dot\alpha}M_{\mu\nu}$

And in my calculation $\sigma^\mu =(iI,\vec\sigma), \bar\sigma^\mu =(-iI,-\vec\sigma) \quad M_\alpha^\beta = -\frac{1}{4}\sigma^{\mu\dot\alpha\beta}\sigma^{\nu\alpha\dot\alpha}M_{\mu\nu}$

[image]